# Invoke-WebRequest produces a corrupt file when downloading from SharePoint using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to download files from our SharePoint locally to my machine using a PowerShell script. When I log into SharePoint and run the following command, I get a corrupt file which is roughly half of the size of the file on SharePoint.
`InvokeWebRequest "https://our.sharepoint.com/Docs/file.pptx" -OutFile out.pptx`

When I drop `-OutFile out.pptx` from the command a new Chrome tab opens to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/cookiesdisabled`

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

I've also tried `System.Net.WebClient` and its `DownloadFile` but I keep getting a `Unathorized 401`even when I set the credentials. I guess I'm missing something but I'm not sure what.

Comment: SharePoint lets you sync files and whole folders locally to your computer. If you do that it would just be a matter of having PowerShell copy/move the file from one local folder to another. Look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sync-sharepoint-files-with-the-onedrive-for-business-sync-client-groove-exe-59b1de2b-519e-4d3a-8f45-51647cf291cd) for more info.

Comment: I know SharePoint can be synced locally, but this is exactly what I don't want. The idea is to have a PowerShell script that will be used by many users to download a particular file from the SharePoint server. We want to make file updates in one place(SharePoint) and have those changes available to everyone with the execution of a script.

Comment: Your sharepoint site looks like it is possibly office 365, so is secured using oauth2, you'll need to authenticate first. Google: invoke-webrequest oauth2

Comment: It is office 365 sharepoint indeed. Ok thanks, I will look into that.

Comment: @David Martin can you please give me an example of how to use oauth? I came across a a few examples online but they all rely on an api. I'm not sure our SharePoint has one since. our.sharepoint.com/_api/ is not not found.